# How to write a Jenkins pipeline job that will install postgreSQL on my system?

Tags: postgresql, jenkins-pipeline

I have to create a jenkins pipeline job which will install postgreSQL.
Decide by yourself about the inputs from the user and the pipeline stages.

I have installed postgreSQL on my machine but how to create a pipeline job for that.

Comment: Is there any particular part that you are stuck? Do you have some code/conf developed already that isn't working correctly?

Comment: can you give me some example on how to write postgress installation script for pipeline?

Comment: Why install postgres in a pipeline?  It's much more common to run postgres in docker in a pipeline.

Comment: I understand that but I am new to jenkins & started learning few days back & my instructor wanted me to do this